# Lost audio after upgrading from 10.04 to 10.10

Tags: 10.10, sound, pulseaudio

Just did an upgrade on my laptop from 10.04 to 10.10, and audio doesn't work at all anymore. I have the indicator applet, and it *seems* like everything is working fine. I've even tried installing several mixers in case something is muted, but nothing is (and mixers are showing activity as if everything is working fine).

No application is reporting any errors, they all seem to be playing happily, but no sound comes out. I've tried reinstalling PulseAudio with --purge but that didn't help either.

(If you need any logs or command output please let me know in the comments, I don't know where to look..)

Things tried so far:

- Creating a new user to eliminate any configuration problems
- Creating /etc/asound.conf with [these instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio#ALSA%20Configuration)
- `sudo apt-get install libxine1-ffmpeg`
- Booted from a live CD (10.04) to eliminate any hardware problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more research and found a "solution".

After a lot of googling, finally ran into this launchpad bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/617647

After seeing [comment #39](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/617647/comments/39) mentioning my laptop model, I've modified my alsa-base.conf and restarted. In more detail:

1. `sudo vi /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (or some other editor instead of Vi)
2. Append the following at the end of the file:

   ```
   alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
   options snd-hda-intel model=auto
   ```
3. Reboot

**Warning:** These instructions should only be used with the models mentioned in the launchpad bug discussion and not just on *any* configuration.

To be honest, I'm not sure what the lines above actually *do*, but my noob instinct tells me it helps ALSA detect the proper sound card model and load the appropriate driver.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a new Ubuntu user just for testing, to see if it is some config causing the trouble?

Try this:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio#ALSA%20Configuration

Comment: Tried adding a new user, no dice. Did you mean I should try creatig `/etc/asound.conf` or something else from your link?

Comment: @dr-hannibal-lecter Edit your question with the updated things you have tried so that it doesn't get buried in the comments.

Comment: @Jorge: Edited, sorry about that.

Comment: No need to apologize! Check the faq to see how editing your questions and adding more details helps you get your problem fixed quicker: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: Yes, have you tried the /etc/asound.conf ?

Comment: @lovinglinux: just tried it, no dice :(

Answer (score 1):

try sudo apt-get install libxine1-ffmpeg

Comment: Nope, still nothing :(