# Dual sound from headphones and speakers

Tags: 10.10, sound, headphones

I have tried everything from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9040/no-audio-with-headphones-but-audio-works-with-integrated-speakers) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100/sound-comes-out-of-my-speakers-even-when-headphones-are-plugged-in) and I have nothing. I have an asus K50IJ and I just can not seem to get head phones working solo.

According to `lspci` I have

> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)

I am running Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "working solo"? Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here. Any solution?
I keep searching

Comment: this is a bug in alsa's HDA Intel driver - it needs some configuration options added to the conf file - if an alsa expert doesn't give you the flags I will try to dig them up for you.

Comment: fortunately i'm not the only one...

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I use a "simple hack" to solve this issue:

To listen to your headphones only, go to Sound Preferences --> Output and from the "Connector" dropdown Choose "Analog Headphones". When you want the sound back to your speaker go back and select the option "Analog Speakers".

(yes, I know it's stupid, but at least I can listen to my headphones without disturbing other persons in the room)

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work. I actually get no sound then.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a bit of thread necromancy, but an answer I found with my Ubuntu 10.10 system, with the joys of PulseAudio installed ..

The "Analog Headphones" setting didn't provide any sound anywhere for me, but I found that both ports were active when I selected "Analog Speakers". So now I just turn my speakers off and put the headphones on when I want headphones (Skype, etc). No auto switching, but it's workable for me!

(PS the AudioEngine A2s are surprisingly fantastic! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the steps on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1811178

It resolved the issue in my Acer Aspire One machine.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with the same problem, I use Ubuntu 11.10, and some hours ago, I installed Xfce to try it. When I went back to Unity and tryed listen to music, the speakers and headphones were working simultaneously.  Then I remembered I had that problem some time ago, and I hardly remembered I fixed it removing PulseAudio and installing Alsamixer. In this case I already had installed alsamixer, then I went to the terminal and used the command alsamixer, then I press F6 to select the apropiate sound car, then move with the arrows until select Auto-Mute, it's very probably you will find it Disabled, just turn it to Enable and the problem will be fixed... Excuse for my bad English... I hope my answer help you.