# I Upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 now I have no Bluetooth working and Intgrated audio disappeared from pulseaudio-output-list

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, headphones

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and all bluetooth-devices and motherboard integrated audio stopped to work.

Also my integrated motherboard audio card Intel PCH disappeared from Gnome sound-list, now I only see HDMI (my monitor), but in alsamixer I see also my Intel PCH.

Firstly I liked to resolve this bluetooth-issue. Intel PCH is irrelevent, I rarely use the nonBT headphones.

When I restart the system, log out from vm/de the Gnome will be in Airplane mode, it takes no effect if I run:
`sudo systemctl enable blutooth`

I have tried also using lxde, but there is same bluetooth-issue and integraded audio issue.

USB-audio seems to work fine.

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
    [  112.322231]
```

```
hcitool scan
Device is not available: No such device
```

```
dmesg
[  112.322231] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3005 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c01e Logitech, Inc. MX518 Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0723 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL827L SD/MMC/MS Flash Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1415:2000 Nam Tai E&E Products Ltd. or OmniVision Technologies, Inc. Sony Playstation Eye
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
sudo blueman-manager
blueman-manager version 2.1.2 starting
blueman-manager 13.28.19 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
```

```
hciconfig
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:3 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1 errors:0
```

```
hcitool -i hci0 lescan
Invalid device: Network is down
```

```
systemctl | grep -i blu
  sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1d.0-usb2-2\x2d1-2\x2d1.7-2\x2d1.7:1.0-bluetooth-hci0.device                         loaded active plugged   /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 
  sys-subsystem-bluetooth-devices-hci0.device                                                                         loaded active plugged   /sys/subsystem/bluetooth/devices/hci0                                        
  bluetooth.service                                                                                                   loaded active running   Bluetooth service                                                            
  bluetooth.target                                                                                                    loaded active active    Bluetooth
```

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
[    9.140290] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    9.140303] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    9.140306] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    9.140307] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    9.140310] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   11.230357] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.230358] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.230362] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z68 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 3GB] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
04:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362 SATA Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
06:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 01)
08:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 11
```

```
uname -a
Linux hostname 5.4.0-51-lowlatency #56-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Oct 5 15:52:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I upgraded kernel so(No effect tho):

```
uname -a
Linux hostname 5.9.0-050900-lowlatency #202010112230 SMP PREEMPT Sun Oct 11 22:37:09 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS \n \l
```

I have tried these solutions, but they did'nt seem to work for me:

- [No audio with headphones, but audio works with integrated speakers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9040/no-audio-with-headphones-but-audio-works-with-integrated-speakers)
- [Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231074/ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-not-working)
- [[ FIX ] Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth doesn't Turn On](https://techstoriesindia.blogspot.com/2020/05/fix-ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-doesnt-turn-on.html)

Screenshots:

- [VM/DE starts with Airplane mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y6u0.png)
- [BT still off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqmk0.png)
- [terminal hcitool and bluetoothctl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBDyN.png)
- [Menu BT off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5bCd.png)
- [Menu no other audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFyEE.png)
- [Alsamixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFyEE.png)

Comment: This is not an answer, but [keep in mind](https://www.zdnet.com/article/google-warns-of-severe-bleedingtooth-bluetooth-flaw-in-linux-kernel/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got headphones also working

I Edited this file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
and changed

```
### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
#load-module module-alsa-sink
```

to this (commented alsa-sink

```
### Load audio drivers statically
### (it's probably better to not load these drivers manually, but instead
### use module-udev-detect -- see below -- for doing this automatically)
load-module module-alsa-sink
```

and restarted the system and I got things working 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I had an bluetooth Hardware issue.
This just happens sometimes. In my case Bluetooth broke, when I upgraded to newer Os probably got some electric-pike or something like that.

I bought new dongle and instantly when attached dongle to usb-port Gnomeshowed that Bluetooth is now on.

```
bluetoothctl 
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# exit
user@hostname:~$ hciconfig
hci1:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:1A:7D:DA:71:13  ACL MTU: 310:10  SCO MTU: 64:8
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:730 acl:0 sco:0 events:56 errors:0
    TX bytes:4877 acl:0 sco:0 commands:56 errors:0

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:3 acl:0 sco:0 commands:1 errors:0

user@hostname:~$ hcitool -i hci1 scan
Scanning ...
```

Now only issue is Intel PCH